# La función no existe después de actualizar versión de dependencia en package.json

Tags: npm, webpack, dependencias, yarn

Estoy desarrollando un módulo que es usado por varios proyectos. Mi módulo usa [polished](https://polished.js.org/) para funciones relacionadas con los colores, en concreto la versión 2.3.1 como se indica en el `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "peerDependencies": {
    ...
    "polished": "2.3.1"
  },
  ...
}
```

Ahora quiero usar una versión más moderna de polished (3.4.0) porque incluye una función nueva que me interesa. Actualicé el número de versión en mi `package.json`, realicé el cambio, comprobé que funcionaba y mandé el nuevo paquete al repositorio.

En dos de los proyectos funciona bien. Pero en el tercero, cuando actualizó a la última versión de mi módulo, éste deja de funcionar. En concreto muestra este mensaje en la consola y termina la ejecución:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Siguiendo el stack trace, llegó a la raíz del problema que es la nueva función que he añadido (`meetsContrastGuidelines`).

Mirando el `package.json` del proyecto (no el de mi módulo), veo que no tiene ninguna referencia a polished. Pero incluye otra dependencia que a su vez incluía una versión antigua de polished que contenía todas los métodos que usamos (básicamente funcionaba de rebote).

Entonces en ese `package.json` añadí la nueva versión de mi módulo y de polished como dependencia (los comentarios son sólo aquí):

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "modulo1": "0.0.1",   // este módulo usa polished 1 
    "mimodulo": "0.4.0",  // la última versión de mi módulo
    "polished": "3.4.0"   // la versión de polished que necesito
  },
  ...
}
```

También borré `node_modules`, instalé los paquetes usando `yarn install`, compilé y corrí el proyecto... y me sigue dando el mismo fallo.

He comprobado en `node_modules` y la versión de polished es 3.4.0 (la correcta). Pero parece como si no se tomara la correcta y se siguiese tomando la antigua.

Probé a borrar la caché de npm y yarn y repetir el proceso, pero el resultado es el mismo.

También probe a añadir la librería directamente no como dependencia pero en resolutions, quedando así aunque siguió sin funcionar:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "modulo1": "0.0.1",   // este módulo usa polished 1 
    "mimodulo": "0.4.0",  // la última versión de mi módulo
  },
  resolutions: {
    ...
    "polished": "3.4.0"   // la versión de polished que necesito
  },
  ...
}
```

¿Qué puede estar pasando y cómo puedo resolverlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que como polished viene con el otro módulo, se ignora la versión especificada en el `package.json` (aún necesito encontrar documentación sobre por qué ocurre esto).

La solución por la que optamos fue actualizar la versión de polished que utilizaba el otro módulo (era un módulo interno que iba a funcionar con la nueva versión sin problemas). Entonces ya no necesitamos especificar polished en ninguna parte (como estaba originalmente).

El `package.json` quedó así al final:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "modulo1": "0.0.2",   // este módulo usa polished 3 en lugar de 1 
    "mimodulo": "0.4.0",  // la última versión de mi módulo
  },
  ...
}
```